# Как исправить переход на страницу Java, и почему второй Override подсвечивается красным?

Tags: java, android

```
package com.example.myapplication_1;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
public Button sum;
public Button minus;
public Button umn;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    sum = (Button) findViewById(R.id.sum);
    minus = (Button) findViewById(R.id.minus);
    umn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.umn);

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (v == sum) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, sum.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }else if (v == minus){
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, minus.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }

    }
}
```

Почему второй Override подсвечивается красным, и почему без него переход на другую страницу не осуществляется?
Java только начал заниматься

Comment: код должен быть кодом а не ссылкой. А ответ простой, вы интерфейс не подключили в объявлении класса. `impliment OnClickListener` или что-то такое.

Comment: Можно поподробнее, я только начал заниматься

Comment: подробнее - не с той стороны вы начали. Вот когда вы подключите кнопки, будете подключать обработчик - тогда вам и подскажет IDE что надо писать. Сейчас она говорит что вы написали ненужный метод. 

P.S. очень грубо

Comment: А как правильно?

Comment: а это смотря что вам надо) кнопки все null нигде не созданы. Обработчик не приклеплён. Ресурсные файлы не приложены.

Comment: Из этого не пойму как сделать переход на 3 страницы по нажатию на кнопки, код изменил

Comment: стало ещё хуже :D в момент создания класса (!) разметки ещё нет и `findView` ничего не найдёт. Перенесите их инициализацию в `onCreate`, дальше я не знаю что у вас в разметке, но думаю надо будет написать `sum.setOnClickListener(this)` дальше уже IDE посдкажет.

Comment: Метод onClick нужно прицеплять к кнопкам, а не просто вставлять в код куда вставилось. Почитайте туториал какой-нибудь про кнопки, что ли.

Answer (score 1):

Красным у вас подчеркивает, потому что метод `onClick` заявлен в интерфейсе `OnClickListener`, который Вы в свою очередь забыли реализовать в вашем `activity`. Грубо говоря, код вашего `activity` должен выглядеть примерно так:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Button summButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.sum);
        Button minusButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.minus);
        Button umnButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.umn);

        summButton.setOnClickListener(this);
        minusButton.setOnClickListener(this);
        umnButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch(v.getId()){
           case R.id.sum:
             startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, sum.class));
             break;
           case R.id.sum:
             startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, minus.class));
             break;
       }
    }    
}
```

Подробнее можно ознакомиться [тут](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnClickListener). И советую также почитать про java code conventions.